# What is difference between Auth::onceUsingID() and Auth::setUser() in Laravel-8

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, impersonation

I want to implement **Impersonate** functionality into Laravel-8 without using any package.

- Only super-admin can use this functionality.
- I used laravel sanctum to authenticate.
- to access impersonate functionality user should be super-admin. (is_admin(boolean) flag is set into users table).

Here is my middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ImpersonateUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $impersonateId = $request->cookie('x-impersonate-id');
        if($request->user()->is_admin && $impersonateId) {
            $user = User::findOrFail($impersonateId);
            if($user->is_admin) {
                return response()->json(["message" => trans("You cannot impersonate an admin account.")], 400);
            }
            Auth::setUser($user);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

My route file:

```
    // Impersonate routes.
    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'impersonate'])->group(function () {
        // checklist routes
        Route::get('checklists', [ChecklistController::class, "index"]);
    });
```

Whether use **Auth::setUser($user)** is safe or I have to use **Auth::onceUsingId($userId);** ?

**Auth::onceUsingId($userId);** not working with `auth::sanctum` middleware. So **Auth::setUser($user)** is safe or not?

I used laravel to develop backend API only.(SPA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should be the same in terms of safety. `OnceUsingId()` calls `setUser()` in the background.

From the [Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php#L249)

> ```
> /**
>  * Log the given user ID into the application without sessions or cookies.
>  *
>  * @param  mixed  $id
>  * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|false
>  */
> public function onceUsingId($id)
> {
>     if (! is_null($user = $this->provider->retrieveById($id))) {
>         $this->setUser($user);
>
>         return $user;
>     }
>
>     return false;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Set the current user.
>  *
>  * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
>  * @return $this
>  */
> public function setUser(AuthenticatableContract $user)
> {
>     $this->user = $user;
>
>     $this->loggedOut = false;
>
>     $this->fireAuthenticatedEvent($user);
>
>     return $this;
> }
> ```

Both of these methods come from the SessionGuard though. I don't know if Sanctum implements its own version.